# Streaming writes to a downloading file from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to generate very large PDF files in a browser and it is not feasible to do this with very large amounts of data, because browsers end up running out of memory before the document is completed. Therefore, I'm looking into a way to stream writes into a file, one page at a time, so that I can free up memory once I finish writing a page.

While I obviously don't get file managing capabilities in browsers (obviously), Jimmy Wärting came up with a most interesting solution in [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js). The main idea here is to use a ServiceWorker to mock an HTTP request with Content-Disposition: Header, which will start a download, and then pipe the data through it.

The issues with these approach are mainly of compatibility: Service Workers aren't supported in all browsers, nor are Web Streams, and they force us to use HTTPS, which may not be feasible in some scenarios. So I wonder whether there is an alternative approach that doesn't involve the use cutting-edge features?

Comment: can u use an inline worker and node streams. in that way u cut out reqmt for service-worker and you buffer the writes of your large data reqmt

Comment: @RobertRowntree The point of a service worker is to download something from a "remote server", or tricking the browser to believe that you are doing just that. I don't see how you could stream writes into a downloaded file using an inline worker. (Yes, I can use a stream, but wouldn't that stream live in memory all the time?)

Comment: What StreamSaver.js does is already an (awesome) *hack* (in the best sense of the term). I am rather confident that you can't achieve this without these "*cutting-edge features*" (or a real server).

Comment: what about using http to chunk it? headers include "100-continue" and mime type of "chunked"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve streamserver kind of things with legacy web capabilities without a hacky way(may be storing the streamed data in [IndexDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) which has [relatively more support](https://caniuse.com/#search=indexdb), still not all), there is a reason to not choose latest web standards like PWA-service workers. IndexedDB is pretty much part of PWA as well, but the question is what suits as your solution better.

[Service workers are available in most major browsers now](https://caniuse.com/#search=service%20workers). If you are still concerned of supporting users in older versions of browser, you can consider using [polyfill](https://github.com/googlearchive/topeka/blob/master/sw.js) to support service worker for them. With less developers concerned of supporting old browsers on such use cases, you might find less documentation/support around such polyfill implementation.